# Non linear State Machine Pattern

Tags: solidity, remix

The State Machine presented at [solidity documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.7.0/common-patterns.html#state-machine) shows a good way to implement the pattern in linear cases. However, when the states don't transact in a non-linear manner there is no example. Could someone inlight how can I use this pattern for non-linear state transaction?

Comment: Can't you replace `stage = Stages(uint(stage) + 1);` by `stage = Stages(f(stage))`. Where `f` is the non-linear function?

Comment: that's a good idea! but how can I make function `f()` depend on the function the user calls? Because in my case if the user decides to call the function `a()` the stage is `A`, but if the user decides to call `b()` the stage will be `B` @hrkrshnn

Comment: This depends on your design. If the non-linear function is independent of function calls, then the above technique would work. Otherwise, perhaps `f` can accept another parameter? If the state changes are even more specific, I think it's better to have the logic inside the function call, rather than use a generic modifier.

Comment: i ended up by making `f` accept another parameter. thanks